# VBA SaveAs method not saving file, no errors?

Tags: vba, excel

Before anyone quickflags this: no, I did not forget to actually save the file after GetSaveAsFilename.

Basically, I've got a big VBA module that starts with an Excel file, processes a bunch of data, and generates a summary in Excel. I want it to be impossible to overwrite the file, and I need it to work in all cases (network drives, opening from email, etc). This is why I thought it would be best just to open a SaveAs box--leave the onus of the path on the user. However, when I trigger this method by saving with macros enabled, everything behaves as expected except the file itself does not save. The debugger says that fileName is what it should be at the time the SaveAs method is called, so I'm truly stumped here. There's no error thrown.

Thanks to anyone who can help! My code is below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim fileName As String, oldName As String, fullName As String
Dim fragName() As String, noExtension As String, filePath As String
Dim newName As String

Cancel = True
oldName = ThisWorkbook.Name
fullName = ThisWorkbook.fullName
fragName() = Split(fullName, ".", 2)
noExtension = fragName(0)
filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
Application.enableEvents = False

enterName:
fileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=filePath, _
    FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Worksheet (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
On Error GoTo getOut

If fullName = fileName Then
MsgBox ("You have chosen the same name, " & oldName & vbCr _
& ", please choose something different.")
GoTo enterName

ElseIf fileName = "False" Then GoTo getOut

End If

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs (fileName)

getOut:
Application.enableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing that the problem is that this code is in the workbook_beforesave event. It's probably causing some infinite recursion or just not allowing the saveas method inside of the event.

Comment: You've set cancel = true.  This prevents the workbook from saving.

Comment: I originally thought the problem might be that I needed to enable events before the SaveAs method, but that caused the infinite loop you refer to. I added "Cancel = False" before the SaveAs call and it's not working any better. I think the Cancel is referring to the user save event and that might be different from the SaveAs call--I've gotten this subroutine to save with Cancel = True before.

Comment: So I'd just like to add this comment for onlookers - I'm not convinced this is the right solution. I think setting Cancel to False in this subroutine will just allow the original save (overwrite) to go through.

Comment: You might be running into problems trying to save this file as a .xlsx file, since it has macros.

Comment: You called it. I wanted to get rid of the macros just to simplify things, but it's not a dealbreaker.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kyle's comment on my original question, I've figured out that the solution was to change

```
fileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=filePath, _
FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Worksheet (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
```

to:

```
fileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=filePath, _
FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
```

Ideally I'd be able to get rid of the macros but this answers the question.